# Extract word in quotes from string

Tags: r, regex

I am using R to extract words from short text pieces. Specifically, I want to extract any word that appear in quotes (") from a string, but not when it appears inside brackets ().

For instance, I would like the "hello" first of the 3 strings, but not the other two:

```
c('"hello" world', 'hello world', '("hello") world')
```

**Original code attempt**

```
str_extract(x, '(?<=")[^$]+(?<=")')
```

Comment: In the end, I used your code to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with nested look arounds in `str_extract`:

```sh
(?<=(?<!\()")[^"]+(?=(?!\))")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3og0Y/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=(?<!\()")`: Assert that we have a `"` before but don't have a `(` before `"`
- `[^"]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `"`
- `(?=(?!\))")`: Assert that we have a `"` after but don't have a `)` after `"`

**Code:**

```sh
str_extract(x, '(?<=(?<!\\()")[^"]+(?=(?!\\))")')
```

or avoid double escaping by using a character class:

```sh
str_extract(x, '(?<=(?<![(])")[^"]+(?=(?![)])")')
```

Comment: the following: `str_extract(x, '(?<=(?<!\()")[^"]+(?=(?!\))")')` gives me the error: `Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'(?<=(?<!\("`

Comment: You will need to double slash it. `str_extract(x, '(?<=(?<!\\()")[^"]+(?=(?!\\))")')`

Comment: Doesn't simple look around suffice? `cat(str_extract(x, '(?<!\\()"[^"]+"(?!\\))'))`

Comment: But that will match `"hello"` instead of `hello`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(grepl('\\("', str1), NA,  str_extract(str1, '(?<=")\\w+'))
#[1] "hello" NA      NA
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("\"hello\" world", "hello world", "(\"hello\") world")
```

Comment: that works for the first two, but not the third case `("hello") world`